# How to remove text between () in a python list?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am still quite unexperienced and hope you can help me. I have tried a lot of different approaches in order to remove some text between `()` in a python3 `list`, but I haven't been successful so far (tried e.g. regex, split, join replace, remove, lambda etc.).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://www.iban.com/country-codes')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")


output = [[cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all('td')[0:2]]
        for row in soup.find_all("tr")]

for i in range(1, len(output)):
    print('Name of country "' + (output[i][0]) + '"')
    print('Country code"' + (output[i][1]) + '"')
    print('')
```

This code produces the following output

```
Name of country "United States of America (the)"
Country code"US"

Name of country "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)"
Country code"VE"
```

But I would like to remove all text between (), e.g. the "(the)" and "(Bolivarian Republic of)" in the above example output, so output would be

```
Name of country "United States of America"
Country code"US"
    
Name of country "Venezuela"
Country code"VE"
```

I am very sorry if this is an answer which has been answered before, but I haven't been able to finde the answer to my question and I have been searching a lot before I gave up :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `.split()` to split by  `(` and pick the first element from result:

```
[e.split(' (')[0] for e in row.stripped_strings]
```

##### Example

Instead of just printing the results, convert and store them in a more structured way, that could be easy transformed to other formats.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://www.iban.com/country-codes')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

d = []
for row in soup.select('table tbody tr'):
    d .append(
        dict(
            zip(
                soup.select_one('table tr:has(th)').stripped_strings,
                [e.split(' (')[0] for e in row.stripped_strings]
            )
        )
    )
print(d)
```

##### Output for US

```
{'Country': 'United States of America', 'Alpha-2 code': 'US', 'Alpha-3 code': 'USA', 'Numeric': '840'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @HedgeHog. Your answer did help me produce the desired output.